# Select layer by location and copying features from multiple shapefiles to multiple shapefiles

Tags: r

I want to apply the reverse of the intersection tool between two shapes several times for different shapefiles. I have 95 point features in folder A, each representing a species location. In folder B, I have 95 polygon buffer areas, each representing potential locations for the 95 species. For instance, I want to pair species 1 in folder A, with species 1 in folder B, species 2 in A with species 2 in B and so on. From there I want to get the points that do not overlap between every pair of features.

In ArcGIS Pro I use select layer by location and set intersection as the spatial relationship, then check "invert spatial relationship", finally I generate a copy of the features that do not overlap.

For every species, I tried something like this but still need to define a method of pairing for every species in the two folders:

[image]

In selecting features I added all 95 species in a single feature shapefile

In R the code for a single pair of shapefiles is as follows:

```
set_here()
library(here)
library(sf)
library(dismo)
library(spex)

presence.data <- st_read(here("data/presence_data.shp")) %>%
  st_transform("+proj=utm +zone=17 +datum=WGS84")

hs_spp <- st_read(here("data/hs_spp.shp")) %>%
  st_transform("+proj=utm +zone=17 +datum=WGS84")

presence.buffer <- st_buffer(presence.data, dist = 5000, endCapStyle = 'ROUND')

absence.data <- st_difference(hs_spp, st_union(presence.buffer))

st_write(absence.data, here("/scratch/abs.shp"))
```

How can I generate an output future shapefile that represents the points not overlapping with a buffer for every 95 species using R?

Comment: You say you "can do this" for one shapefile at a time - if you show us that code then it might be easier for us to explain how to do "this" (and its not clear what exactly "this" is) for a set of shapefiles. Please edit your question and show the code you already have.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in ArcCatalog, ArcMap or CMD? I think what you're trying to ask for is that for each shapefile in folder A select by location and if there is a selection write the selected elements to a shapefile to folder B, is this a fair assessment of your question? Do you have any code to start from? a basic code example indicates your python ability to tailor an answer to your experience level.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: Also, please decide which of the GIS products mentioned you want to ask about.  By asking about more than one you are effectively asking multiple questions which goes against the [Tour].

Comment: Thank you all, I edited again my request.